# Comparing a string (variable) in a WHERE statement

Tags: php, sql

I've got PHP script that uses an SQL query to save JSON in a variable. The query is something like this (I've changed the names of the columns to something more general)

```
$value = $_GET['value'];

SELECT column1 AS 'col1', column2 AS 'col2', column3 AS 'col3', column4 AS 'col4', column5 AS 'col5'
FROM db.dbo.table
WHERE column5 = $value
```

The variable comes from another page, and it is a string that may or may not contain a space. However, this does not return any JSON and I'm not sure why (It just returns `[]`). This example script works perfectly in SQL Server, but when I try to run it in PHP, it doesn't work. If I get rid of the line `WHERE column5 = $value`, the script returns JSON. This is the line that passes the variable in a JS script on the other page

```
return '<a href="/script.php?value=' + data + '" target="_blank">Example</a>'
```

I'm sure it's something minor, but can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Missing quotes. `...WHERE column5 = '$value'`. Also don't forget escaping the params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach (apart from not using prepared statements).

The first is that you *trust* user input:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
```

This should be replaced by some kind of escaping of `$value`, so that one can't execute arbitrary queries (e.g. in a `SUBSELECT`) and cause denial of services, or worse, if some query allows issuing `DELETE` or `DROP` commands.

The second problem is that the value may contain spaces, and this would break SQL syntax unless you added quote signs:

```
SELECT column1 AS 'col1', column2 AS 'col2', column3 AS 'col3', column4 AS 'col4', column5 AS 'col5'
FROM db.dbo.table
WHERE column5 = '$value'
```

With a judicious use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), you can defuse both issues in one go.

Another facet of the same second problem is that you might run into escaping problems, if the value passed through the URL contains URL-quoted characters (e.g. +, % and so on), or **encoding** problems if the value crosses an encoding boundary (e.g. the originating page is, or is automatically recognized as, or *might be forced into being recognized as*, ISO-8859-15 and the database is UTF-8, or vice versa. This last issue has no "one-size-fits-all" solution - even if prepared statements *may* help -, and requires you to check carefully either the encoding path of your variables, or force everything to always be converted to UTF-8. You can verify whether you are at risk by placing international characters (e.g. "à") inside the value in the page containing the link, and seeing what happens.

Comment: The value that is passed to the query doesn't come from a user input, so I don't think this is necessary. But this would be a better answer for anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes to your `where` clause:e.g. `where column5 = '$value'`

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I just got confused since this worked for my other script, but that variable was an integer. I forgot that strings need to be wrapped in quotes. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have what you need please be kind enough to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$query="SELECT column1 AS 'col1', column2 AS 'col2', column3 AS 'col3', column4 AS 'col4', column5 AS 'col5' FROM db.dbo.table WHERE column5 ='". $_GET['value']."'";
OR
$query="SELECT column1 AS 'col1', column2 AS 'col2', column3 AS 'col3', column4 AS 'col4', column5 AS 'col5' FROM db.dbo.table WHERE column5 ='". $value."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT column1 AS 'col1', column2 AS 'col2', column3 AS 'col3', column4 AS 'col4', column5 AS 'col5' FROM db.dbo.table WHERE column5 = '$value'";
```